# Set a React-Native MapView Touch Event Handler

Tags: react-native

Is Facebook's MapView just for showing annotations (map markers) ?  There doesn't seem to be a way to add a event hander for a marker touch event.  Do I have to use something like http://react-components.com/component/react-native-mapbox-gl

Answer (score 0):

have you tried onAnnotationPress?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#content

Comment: I've tried the onAnnotationPress on MapView but it doesn't do anything. 

`<MapView
    annotations={this.state.annotations}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    onAnnotationPress={this.onAnnotationPress}
    style={styles.map} />`

and the function to handle it

`onAnnotationPress(id) {
   console.log('onAnnotationPress yooooo' + id);
  },`

Answer (score 0):

Hear is my code works fine

```
    constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
            region : {latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,},
            annotations : [],
          };


       for (var i = 0; i < this.props.list.length; i++) {
             this.state.annotations[i] = {latitude:parseFloat(this.props.list[i].latitude),
                longitude: parseFloat(this.props.list[i].longitude),
                animateDrop: true,
                /*title: this.props.list[i].name,
                subtitle: this.props.list[i].address,*/
                image : require('../images/icons/pharmacy-map-normal.png'),
                id : i.toString()}
       };
     }

    render() {
       return (
         <View>
           <MapView
             style={styles.map}
             showsUserLocation={true}
             region={this.state.region}
             onAnnotationPress={this.onAnnotationPress}
             annotations={this.state.annotations}>
             </MapView>
         </View>
       );
     }

onAnnotationPress =(annotation) =>{
    alert(annotation.id)
 }
```